# Extracting data from JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I have a column which holds the following data named events_payload:

```
{
    "event": 'number_1"
    }

    ,
    "position":null,
    "page_setup": {
        "revision": 45190, "template":"\"This is\" new template", "date_modified":"2020-02-26 08:11:52", "category":"best-tv"
    }
}
```

I am trying to create new columns by extracting the JSON so that I would have columns like so:

```
revision    template               date_modified         category
45190       This is new template   2020-02-26 08:11:52   best-tv
```

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT
json_extract_path_text(events.event_payload::text, 'revision'::text, true) AS revision
```

But I do not know how to take what is inside the `page_setup` one element at a time.

How could I extract all 4 data fields into separate columns?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I am using Postgres in AWS redshift/

Comment: no - you are using redshift and redshift <> postgres ESPECIALLY in regards to json. To answer your question - just repeat what you have for revision for the 3 other items. or do you not know upfront what these items will be?